# Rails assets pipeline not getting precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am trying to deploy a rails application on Heroku. The the deployment was successful but when I visited the link it loaded:

We're sorry, but something went wrong.

My Heroku Logs:

```
2013-06-19T05:38:11.283378+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `worker_loop'
2013-06-19T05:38:11.283378+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
2013-06-19T05:38:11.283378+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T05:38:11.283378+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2013-06-19T05:38:11.283378+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T05:38:11.283205+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-06-19T05:38:11.283378+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
2013-06-19T05:38:11.283378+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2013-06-19T05:38:11.605271+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=iface.herokuapp.com fwd="1.38.20.65" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-06-19T05:46:35.840790+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8cb868f by nitin9003@gmail.com
2013-06-19T05:46:35.868513+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v14 created by nitin9003@gmail.com
2013-06-19T05:46:35.922569+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8cb868f by nitin9003@gmail.com
2013-06-19T05:46:36.324147+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-06-19T05:46:41.282127+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-06-19T05:46:41.643826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 26808 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2013-06-19T05:46:42.205959+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2013-06-19T05:46:42.205959+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2013-06-19T05:46:42.211787+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2013-06-19T05:46:42.211899+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead
2013-06-19T05:46:42.521138+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-19T05:46:42.520941 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 12 exit 0> worker=2
2013-06-19T05:46:42.931268+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-19T05:46:42.931050 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 6 exit 0> worker=0
2013-06-19T05:46:43.034955+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-19T05:46:43.034726 #2]  INFO -- : master complete
2013-06-19T05:46:43.034537+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-19T05:46:43.034330 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 9 exit 0> worker=1
2013-06-19T05:46:43.542795+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-19T05:46:43.542380 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2013-06-19T05:46:44.987862+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2013-06-19T05:46:46.870812+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-19T05:46:46.871078+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-19T05:46:48.902214+00:00 app[web.1]:         SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
2013-06-19T05:46:48.902214+00:00 app[web.1]:         future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.
2013-06-19T05:46:48.902214+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T05:46:48.902214+00:00 app[web.1]:         This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
2013-06-19T05:46:48.902214+00:00 app[web.1]:         provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
2013-06-19T05:46:48.902214+00:00 app[web.1]:         cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
2013-06-19T05:46:48.902214+00:00 app[web.1]:         Called from: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
2013-06-19T05:46:48.902214+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T05:46:49.604717+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-19T05:46:49.604512 #2]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:26808 fd=11
2013-06-19T05:46:49.659527+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-19T05:46:49.658277 #6]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2013-06-19T05:46:49.686315+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-19T05:46:49.685073 #9]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
2013-06-19T05:46:49.698603+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-19T05:46:49.698296 #2]  INFO -- : master process ready
2013-06-19T05:46:49.723342+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-06-19T05:46:49.722972 #12]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
2013-06-19T05:46:49.784187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-06-19T05:46:50.995400+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T05:46:50.995400+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T05:46:50.995400+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/public" for 1.38.20.65 at 2013-06-19 05:46:50 +0000
2013-06-19T05:46:51.182896+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PublicController#index as HTML
2013-06-19T05:46:51.294000+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered public/index.html.erb within layouts/application (50.5ms)
2013-06-19T05:46:51.327417+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/public host=iface.herokuapp.com fwd="1.38.20.65" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=537ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-06-19T05:46:51.316108+00:00 app[web.1]:     16: 
2013-06-19T05:46:51.316108+00:00 app[web.1]:     17: <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
2013-06-19T05:46:51.316108+00:00 app[web.1]:     18: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.css" %>
2013-06-19T05:46:51.316108+00:00 app[web.1]:     19: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "responsive.css" %>
2013-06-19T05:46:51.308266+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 125ms
2013-06-19T05:46:51.316108+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T05:46:51.316108+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (bootstrap.css isn't precompiled):
2013-06-19T05:46:51.316108+00:00 app[web.1]:     15: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2013-06-19T05:46:51.316108+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
2013-06-19T05:46:51.316108+00:00 app[web.1]:     21: 
2013-06-19T05:46:51.316108+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__942151506316232271_24121720'
2013-06-19T05:46:51.316324+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T05:46:51.316324+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T05:46:51.955782+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=iface.herokuapp.com fwd="1.38.20.65" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=93ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-06-19T06:11:30.231072+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T06:11:30.231072+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T06:11:30.231072+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/public" for 1.38.20.65 at 2013-06-19 06:11:30 +0000
2013-06-19T06:11:30.444693+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PublicController#index as HTML
2013-06-19T06:11:30.669497+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered public/index.html.erb within layouts/application (77.6ms)
2013-06-19T06:11:30.708867+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 256ms
2013-06-19T06:11:30.715093+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (bootstrap.css isn't precompiled):
2013-06-19T06:11:30.715093+00:00 app[web.1]:     15: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2013-06-19T06:11:30.715093+00:00 app[web.1]:     17: <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
2013-06-19T06:11:30.715093+00:00 app[web.1]:     19: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "responsive.css" %>
2013-06-19T06:11:30.715278+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T06:11:30.715278+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T06:11:30.715093+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T06:11:30.715093+00:00 app[web.1]:     16: 
2013-06-19T06:11:30.715093+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
2013-06-19T06:11:30.715093+00:00 app[web.1]:     21: 
2013-06-19T06:11:30.715093+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__942151506316232271_24178020'
2013-06-19T06:11:30.715093+00:00 app[web.1]:     18: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.css" %>
2013-06-19T06:11:30.725572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/public host=iface.herokuapp.com fwd="1.38.20.65" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=588ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-06-19T06:11:31.519922+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=iface.herokuapp.com fwd="1.38.20.65" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-06-19T06:29:59.349659+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T06:29:59.349659+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/public" for 1.38.20.65 at 2013-06-19 06:29:59 +0000
2013-06-19T06:29:59.349659+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T06:29:59.388827+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PublicController#index as HTML
2013-06-19T06:29:59.412817+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms
2013-06-19T06:29:59.414621+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T06:29:59.414621+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (bootstrap.css isn't precompiled):
2013-06-19T06:29:59.414621+00:00 app[web.1]:     15: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2013-06-19T06:29:59.411020+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered public/index.html.erb within layouts/application (13.3ms)
2013-06-19T06:29:59.414621+00:00 app[web.1]:     16: 
2013-06-19T06:29:59.414621+00:00 app[web.1]:     21: 
2013-06-19T06:29:59.414621+00:00 app[web.1]:     17: <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
2013-06-19T06:29:59.414621+00:00 app[web.1]:     19: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "responsive.css" %>
2013-06-19T06:29:59.414621+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
2013-06-19T06:29:59.414621+00:00 app[web.1]:     18: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.css" %>
2013-06-19T06:29:59.414814+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T06:29:59.414814+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-19T06:29:59.414621+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__942151506316232271_24121720'
2013-06-19T06:29:59.452266+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/public host=iface.herokuapp.com fwd="1.38.20.65" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=108ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-06-19T06:30:00.121551+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=iface.herokuapp.com fwd="1.38.20.65" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0
```

I tried solving the above error by rake assets:precompile but go the below error.

```
iface@iface-VGN-C17G-R:~/sites/iface$ rake assets:precompile
/home/iface/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby /home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  (in /home/iface/sites/iface/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:32:in `resolver'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:25:in `image_url'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/script/funcall.rb:112:in `_perform'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/script/node.rb:40:in `perform'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/script/list.rb:70:in `block in _perform'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/script/list.rb:70:in `map'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/script/list.rb:70:in `_perform'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/script/node.rb:40:in `perform'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:298:in `visit_prop'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109:in `block in visit_children'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108:in `visit_children'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:320:in `visit_rule'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109:in `block in visit_children'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108:in `visit_children'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:128:in `visit_root'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/compressor.rb:12:in `compress'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:243:in `block in css_compressor='
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/tilt-1.3.7/lib/tilt/template.rb:77:in `render'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:177:in `block in evaluate'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `each'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `evaluate'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `new'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `build_asset'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:23:in `block in compile'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/iface/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bi...]
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/iface/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Please Help! Its almost a week now that I am coming across this error.
```

Comment: Please provide your Gemfile

Comment: What are the contents of your `application.css`?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and then precompiling your assets again?

Answer (score 0):

Did u add the bootstrapfiles on your own or used a gem ?
If you added to the assets folder then you need to specify in the config/environments/production.rb what files are to be precompiled.